# How can i solve exponentiation using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to write code that can solve exponentiation using recursion.  For example, suppose that I have:

```
def exponent_calc(base, expo):
    if expo == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return
```

what could i write for the return statement using recursion that will complete this process?

thanks you

Comment: `return base * exponent_calc(base, expo-1)`

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Are there some assumptions you're not telling us?  Like that `expo` has to be an integer?  Possibly positive?

Comment: that solution worked- thank you Primusa.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by @Primusa:

```
def exponent_calc(base, expo): 
   if expo == 0: 
      return 1 

   return base * exponent_calc(base, expo-1)
```